# How can I get Sibelius to add brass tremolo fingerings?

Tags: sibelius

Sibelius has a plugin that can add brass fingerings. But it only writes in one possible fingering (the most common one).

I'd like it to write in two fingerings so that the performer can alternate rapidly between them to give a tremolo effect.

I've dummied up (in mspaint) how I'd like the text to look.

Two questions:

1. Can I do this with the plugin?
2. If I can't, what would be the best way to manually write the fingerings in?

[image]

Comment: It's a tremolo because the pitch doesn't change. For that first minim C natural you can perform it open (zero valves) or with valves 2 and 3. Similar principle for the other notes above - you switch rapidly between the conventional fingering and an alternate fingering.

Comment: Oh right, that makes perfect sense. I think I read "semitone" where it says "semiquaver" — my mistake.

Comment: Why not just write "tremolo" (or the marking)?  Any reasonably experienced player will know what to do.  Otherwise,  put in a "notes" section explaining exactly how you want the tremolos performed.  Stuffing a pile of fingering markings into the score is generally not a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

The Sibelius plugin 'Add Brass Fingering' creates text objects in the Text Style 'Fingering'.  (!)  You can create these manually if you want.

But I suggest you simply write 'trem' or 'valve trem' (to distinguish it from a flutter tongue which might use the same basic notation).  And you don't have to state 'semiquaver'.  Apart from annoying Americans (who will pretend they don't understand it) it's implicit in the notation.

The technique is comprehensively discussed here:
http://themoderntrumpet.com/2020/12/16/trills-shakes-and-tremolos/  I suggest you note Stockhausen's method with interest, but don't copy it!

[image]

Comment: Nice troll on the  "hemisemidemimicroattoquaver" controversy.   Why Europe has embraced meters & centimeters and millimeters but can't comprehend the advantage of   " 1/2^n-note" over polysyllabic trash remains a mystery.